# Can ISPs see my connection with a hidden service if I use Tor2Web or a similar proxy?

Tags: tor2web, internet-service-provider

If I use Tor2Web on a normal web browser such as Google Chrome, can ISPs monitor or intercept my connection with a hidden service?

Comment: Yes probably, tor use specific relays with specific ip. But I think they can't view what you're doing...
If I were you, I'll not use Tor2Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can see that you are connecting to that proxy. They cannot see what you are doing there, because it is HTTPS. However, it is far less secure than using TOR, because, if they seize that proxy server, they can see everything you are doing on the dark web.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up!